# Is HashMap gone from API 23

Tags: android, hashmap

I am using following code to declare hashmap

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and I am shocked that HashMap not found in java.util, I search around me, asking from my seniors but all they are just shocked. So whats going on why it is not working.

**I am using**

1. Android Studio 1.5 32bit
2. API Level 23
3. JDK 8UP45 32bit
4. Windows 7 32bit

---

I tried different solution which users advised me

1. Invalidated the Android Studio (By "Raghavendra" -> not worked)
2. Try another JDK, I tried JDK 7Up80 and 8Up65 (By "Radix" -> not worked)
3. Update Android Studio to 1.5.1 (By my senior -> not worked)
4. Try using HashMap in Java Project using Eclipse (By "Amit Aswal" -> **worked in Eclipse Mars but not in Indigo**)
5. Create a fresh android project and use HashMap (By "CommonsWare" -> not worked)

So now what else I should try now to run HashMap in Android Studio 1.5.1 :(

Comment: does it work if you downgrade to api 22 ?

Comment: Hi @Adnan I am using API 23 but I can use HashMap.. what is the java version u are using?

Comment: 1.8 update 45 @Raghavendra

Comment: I did not checked that, let me check @Radix

Comment: nothing should change even if you downgrade to api 22, since this is a class available via java package and not android. possibly mention your system configurations and java version

Comment: Please try to do invalidate cache and restart..try once

Comment: @Radix it is also not working in API 22.

Comment: @Raghavendra let me invalidate, please wait

Comment: as @CommonsWare has answered, the HashMap class exists in api 23 and no one should have a problem using it. If anything that is wrong is probably with your JDK installation. If you wanna take a stab at it then try reinstalling your JDK. Downgrading to JDK 7 could also be an option.

Comment: @Radix I know that I re investigated on Google after CommonWare confirmed but still I cannot access HashMap. I commented on Amit Aswal below please read that.

Comment: try to install JDK 7 and then create a test project to verify

Comment: same issue ... now what should I do :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HashMap is a class shipped with Java SDK. It doesn't matter which API you are using in Android the core classes of java will work. HashMap support can't be taken of Android as it is a part of Collection framework which helps in creating and managing the data structure in Java.

It exists and can be used in API Level 23. (I am also working in API 23 and using it for various purposes).

There might be some other mistake in your program.

Comment: HashMap on same android version with same API level having same JDK (i.e. 8Up65) is working fine on another PC but not on my computer. I uninstalled all java versions and reinstalled JDK 8Up65, updated my Android Studio to 1.5.1 but still cannot achieved success. I am almost giving up. I tried every solution

Comment: try to create a java program with HashMap to see if it works.

Comment: When I created a project in eclipse as standard java project it gives me this error when importing java.util.HashMap "The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Comment: I got good news, HashMap is not running on Eclipse Indigo but running fine with Mars :) ... now I have a question that why it is not running on Android Studio 1.5.1

Answer (score 2):

> Is HaspMap gone from API 23

`HashMap` [exists in API Level 23](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html), as well as all prior API levels.

> I am using Android Studio 1.5 with API 23 Installed!

I just created a new Android Studio project using Android Studio 1.5.1, accepting all project defaults. The resulting project has `compileSdkVersion` of 23. And I can add `HashMap<String, String>` to `MainActivity.java` without issue.

Comment: when I type HashMap I just see four related results in autocomplete menu that are IdentityHashMap, LinkedHashMap, WeakHashMap, ConcurrentHashMap but not HashMap

Comment: @Adnan: Use the new-project wizard to create a scrap project. Try using `HashMap` in that project's `MainActivity.java`. If it works, then you know that the problem is limited to the project that you have been trying. If it does not work, then you know that the problem is tied to your development environment. For example, I am using Java 7, not Java 8.

Comment: @CommonWare I created a new project still problem persist

Comment: @Adnan: Sorry, but I cannot explain your symptoms.